# c++ if loop and functions

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

In my program it first asks for the number of employees. The if loop says that if the input is input < 1 to output saying "Please enter a value of at least 1". If you input 0 or -1 it outputs for the user to correct it, but it only does this once. So if the user inputs -1 twice it will run the second time. It also does this with the second if loop.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getNumEmployees();
int getDaysMissed(int);
double getAverageDays(int,int);

int main()
{
    int numEmployees;
    int daysMissed;
    double average;

    //Get the number of employees
    numEmployees = getNumEmployees();

    //Get the number of days missed
    daysMissed = getDaysMissed(numEmployees);

    //Get the average days missed
    average = getAverageDays(numEmployees, daysMissed);

    cout << "The average number of days missed is: " << average << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int getNumEmployees()
{
    int employeeNum;

    cout << "Enter the number of company employees: ";
    cin >> employeeNum;

    if(employeeNum < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a value greater than 0 " << endl;
        cin >> employeeNum;
    }

    return employeeNum;
}


int getDaysMissed(int employeeNum)
{
    int totalDays = 0;
    int employee;

    for(int count = 1; count <= employeeNum; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of days employee " << count << " missed: ";
        cin >> employee;
        if(employee < 0)
        {
            cout << "Enter a positive number for days missed " <<     endl;
            cin >> employee;
        }

        totalDays += employee;
    }
    return totalDays;
}

double getAverageDays(int employeeNum, int totalDays)
{
    double averageDays;
    averageDays = totalDays / employeeNum;
    return averageDays;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an if loop.

Comment: An `if` is not a loop.

Comment: Yep, the answer is in the question!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
if(employeeNum < 1)
```

to this:

```
while(employeeNum < 1)
```

You want looping.  And as chris mentions, `if` does no looping.

Comment: Wow thanks i feel stupid, i have no idea why i did that thanks